# Receive data without sending request, e.g. notifying the app when events occured

Tags: android, http

I'm wondering if it is possible to receive a http data e.g. http inputstream without sending http request. Because right now, I can receive data online through `HttpURLConnection.getInputStream()` when sending http request. My question, does it always have to send a request in order to receive a response or any kind of data like input stream or is there a way to regularly receive data? How about the facebook mobile? how does the phone receive data for example facebook notifications while I'm not doing anything?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) Service. Or a push service to push down notifications. You push to their services, and they'll take care of messaging the phones, which wake up your app to handle the notification. You can then choose what to do with that notification, like show it in the notification bar or run some code to update the app in the background.

- [GCM](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)
- [Amazon SNS](http://aws.amazon.com/sns/)